# Android custom view canvas clear fails

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

I'm writing a simple custom `View` that should draw the an RSSI signal shape (two overlapping triangles one filled proportionally with the level of the signal). The components works except for the clearing of canvas.

I tought I need to do something like that:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final int mWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    final int mHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    final float _fillw = mWidth * (mLevel) / 100f;
    final float _fillh = mHeight * (100f - mLevel) / 100f;

    //canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    if (mLevel < mWarnLevel)
        mFillPaint.setColor(mWarnFillColor);
    else if ((mLevel >= mWarnLevel) && (mLevel < mSafeLevel))
        mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);
    else if (mLevel >= mSafeLevel)
        mFillPaint.setColor(mSafeFillColor);

    mFramePath.moveTo(0, mHeight);
    mFramePath.lineTo(mWidth, mHeight);
    mFramePath.lineTo(mWidth, 0);
    mFramePath.close();

    mFillPath.moveTo(0, mHeight);
    mFillPath.lineTo(_fillw, mHeight);
    mFillPath.lineTo(_fillw, _fillh);
    mFillPath.close();

    canvas.drawPath(mFramePath, mFramePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mFillPath, mFillPaint);
}

public void setLevel(int level) {
    if (this.mLevel != level) {
        this.mLevel = level;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

The level is drawn correctly until it grows and the triangle area also get larger. When it start to decrease the area is not *updated* anymore probably beacuse the background is not cleared.
I tried also to use the commented `.drawColor()` line without luck.

P.S. I need to have a transparent background on this `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to clear the path

```
public void clear()
{
 mFramePath.reset();
 mFillPath.reset();
 invalidate();
}
```